# LEFT JOIN only one match per ID

Tags: sql, mysql, left-join

I'm trying to join two tables in a very peculiar way and I can't find the right query to achieve this.
I want to keep ALL dt1 rows intact and join the first row for each FUND_ID with the respective match from dt2.

See below an example for better understanding

First table: dt1

| FUND_ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Fund1 |
| 1 | Fund2 |
| 1 | Fund8 |
| 2 | Fund3 |
| 2 | Fund4 |

Second table: dt2

| FUND_ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 |

Desired Join Result:

| FUND_ID | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fund1 | 100 |
| 1 | Fund2 |  |
| 1 | Fund8 |  |
| 2 | Fund3 | 200 |
| 2 | Fund4 |  |

I tried multiple SQL Queries, using LEFT JOIN and DISTINCT, but I was not able to achieve the expected result.
I expect an output table with all the rows from dt1 where the first row for each FUND_ID is joined with the respective match from dt2.

Comment: How can we identify the first row for each FUND_ID ?

Comment: What is the "first" row? Is that determined by *Name* alphabetically or something else?

Comment: It's the first occurrence of each FUND_ID in the original table.
We can't rely on any field to sort/filter

Comment: That does not answer the question, there is no such thing as a first row or last row unless you define how to order them - eg an ID or timestamp value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a row number to each record within each `FUND_ID` in your first table using `ROW_NUMBER()`. Then you can join this with the second table, but only include the value from the second table for the first row of each `FUND_ID`.

```
WITH RankedDt1 AS (
    SELECT 
        FUND_ID,
        Name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FUND_ID ORDER BY Name) AS RowNum
    FROM
        dt1
)
SELECT
    r.FUND_ID,
    r.Name,
    CASE WHEN r.RowNum = 1 THEN d2.Value END AS Value
FROM
    RankedDt1 r
LEFT JOIN
    dt2 d2
ON
    r.FUND_ID = d2.FUND_ID AND r.RowNum = 1
ORDER BY
    r.FUND_ID, r.RowNum;
```

In a few words, rank each row within each `FUND_ID` in the first table, then join it with the second table, but only bring in the value for the first row in each group.

Comment: And cruicially, that first row is determined by the value of `Name` alphabetically, in this case - which may or may not be what the OP means.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
  SELECT dt1.FUND_ID, dt1.Name, dt2.Value
FROM dt1
LEFT JOIN dt2 ON dt1.FUND_ID = dt2.FUND_ID
AND dt1.Name = (
    SELECT Name
    FROM dt1 dt1_inner
    WHERE dt1_inner.FUND_ID = dt1.FUND_ID
    ORDER BY Name
    LIMIT 1
);
```